# Google Cloud CloudSQL Instance Fails To Create using Terraform Provider With Error "Per-Product Per-Project Service Account is not found"

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql

We're trying to deploy a Cloud SQL (MSSQL) instance using the google-beta provider with a private IP and after roughly four to five minutes it fails and throws the error ***"Error waiting for Create Instance: Per-Product Per-Project Service Account is not found"***

I am able to create a Cloud SQL instance using the service account via the Cloud Shell CLI and manually in Console.

Has anyone encountered this before and can they provide any insights as to what may be going wrong?

If you look at the errored out resource in console, it appears to have mostly created but this error is shown.

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "cloud_sql_instance" {

  provider = google-beta

  name             = var.cloud_sql_instance_name
  region           = var.gcp_region
  database_version = var.cloud_sql_version
  root_password    = "wearenothardcodingplaceholdertest"
  deletion_protection = var.delete_protection_enabled
  project         = var.gcp_project


  settings {
    tier = var.cloud_sql_compute_tier
    availability_type = var.cloud_sql_availibility_type
    collation = var.cloud_sql_collation
    disk_autoresize = var.cloud_sql_auto_disk_resize
    disk_type = var.cloud_sql_disk_type

    active_directory_config {
      domain = var.active_directory_domain
    }

    backup_configuration {
      enabled = var.cloud_sql_backup_enabled
      start_time = var.cloud_sql_backup_starttime
      point_in_time_recovery_enabled = var.cloud_sql_pitr_enabled
      transaction_log_retention_days = var.cloud_sql_log_retention_days

      backup_retention_settings {
        retained_backups = var.cloud_sql_backup_retention_number
        retention_unit = var.cloud_sql_backup_retention_unit
      }

    }

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = var.cloud_sql_backup_public_ip
      private_network = data.google_compute_network.vpc_connection.self_link
      require_ssl = var.cloud_sql_backup_require_ssl
      allocated_ip_range = var.cloud_sql_ip_range_name
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day = var.cloud_sql_patch_day
      hour = var.cloud_sql_patch_hour
      update_track = "stable"
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You may have a look at [this example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance) for additional required resource creation.

Comment: Hi, we have all those resources from the example in our definition (and more).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue. You need to create a Service Identity for sqladmin.googleapis.com.

```
resource "google_project_service_identity" "cloudsql_sa" {
  provider = google-beta

  project = "cool-project"
  service = "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
}
```